# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__users_personal_detail.husband_adhaarcopy

Tags: python, django

I added new fields and file fields and when I ran migrations I got this error.Looks like I am getting error in a FileField .I don't know what's causing this issue.Please help!

```
Applying users.0010_auto_20200228_1138...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__users_personal_detail.husband_adhaarcopy

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 283, in _remake_table
    self.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s" % (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__users_personal_detail.husband_adhaarcopy
```

this is how my models.py looks like.I have given blank=True and null=True for the file field as well,and i think i should have worked fine but when i run python manage.py migrate I get this error.

```
class Personal_Detail(models.Model):
    beneficiary_adhaar_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaarno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaarcopy = models.FileField(upload_to='adhaar/', null=True, blank=True,)


    idcard=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaar_eid=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)    
    beneficiary_id_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    idno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    idcopy=models.FileField(upload_to='identitycard/', null=True, blank=True,)

    husband_adhaar_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    husband_adhaarno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    husband_adhaarcopy = models.FileField(upload_to='adhaar/', null=True, blank=True,)

    husband_idcard=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    husband_adhaar_eid=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)    
    husband_id_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    husband_idno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    husband_idcopy=models.FileField(upload_to='identitycard/', null=True, blank=True,)


    def __str__(self):
          return self.beneficiary_adhaar_name or self.beneficiary_id_name or str(self.pk)
```

Answer (score 2):

First delete all the migrations in your migrations folder except init.py file and then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

hope it works

Comment: i am getting this error when i hit submit, OperationalError at /personal_detail/
table users_personal_detail has no column named husband_adhaar_name

Comment: that means you have not migrated the models to db by running `migrate`